# Linux Installer ISO File

Tags: linux, debian, debian-installer

I have customized Debian distribution in virtual box i.e. made some changes, installed new tools, add and signed new repositories, and some other minor changes. Now, I want to create its installer ISO file. I have searched through internet. I got the installer script of Debian but cannot understand where to make changes in that. I have also tried live-build tool but I don't understand how it works. So I need help.
I want to make an installer ISO file so that I can distribute it to others like debian or ubuntu iso files.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I want to create an installer iso file of that distribution. Installer file means the iso file which users could use to install my customized distribution like we install ubuntu with ubuntu-installer iso file and other distribtions with there installer files.